# how to pass contains filter to sql in LinqToXML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework, linq

I have table like this :

```
    public class ProductAttributeCombination
{
  public string AttributesXml { get; set; }
        public XElement AttributesXmlContent
        {
            get { return XElement.Parse(AttributesXml); }
            set { AttributesXml = value.ToString(); }
        }
        public List<ProductAttributeXML> ProductAttributesXML
        {
            get
            {
                return XElement.Parse(AttributesXml).Elements("Attribute").Select(row => new ProductAttributeXML { AttributeCode = Convert.ToInt32(row.Attribute("Code").Value), AttributeOptionCode= Convert.ToInt32(row.Value) }).ToList();
            }
        }
}
```

and `ProductAttributteXML` like this :

```
   public class ProductAttributeXML
 {

  public int AttributeCode { get; set; }
  public int AttributeOptionCode { get; set; }
}
```

xml result in database like this :

```
<Attributes>
  <Attribute Code="1">2</Attribute>
  <Attribute Code="2">6</Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

**1:**

how can I create a query to row that xmlfield contains  belowe xml:

```
<Attribute Code="1">2</Attribute>
```

**2:**

how can I pass contains filter in xml fields to sql , becuse I dont want get all records , My database is larg and my if I get all rows , my query take long .

I need a way or a library to pass param to sql and filter data . ex. pass attribute Value and code to SQL .

I searched on the NET but I cant find any similar question  and I dont have any idea .

thanks

Comment: Is the XML always as simple as your example? Just Attribute-Nodes with one Code attribute and one element value?

Comment: yes just one node , but some times each `Attributes` can have more than 5 attribute `tag`

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this is what you are looking for:

Just copy the whole lot into an empty query window and execute.
Then play around to find out, what works best for you

--Here your XML with some more nodes

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Attributes>
  <Attribute Code="1">2</Attribute>
  <Attribute Code="2">6</Attribute>
  <Attribute Code="3">11</Attribute>
  <Attribute Code="4">13</Attribute>
  <Attribute Code="5">16</Attribute>
</Attributes>';
```

--Question 1 (all assuming that your XML includes the "Code" only as attribute
within the "Attribute" node

```
SELECT @xml.query('//*[@Code="1"]') AS TheNode
      ,@xml.query('//*[@Code="1"]').value('.','int') AS TheNodesValue
      ,@xml.value('(//*[@Code="1"])[1]','int') AS DirectEvaluation
;
```

--The same is possible with an exteral parameter

```
DECLARE @prm INT=1;
SELECT @xml.query('//*[@Code=sql:variable("@prm")]') AS TheNode
      ,@xml.query('//*[@Code=sql:variable("@prm")]').value('.','int') AS TheNodesValue
      ,@xml.value('(//*[@Code=sql:variable("@prm")])[1]','int') AS DirectEvaluation
;
```

--Question 2: Suggestion: Shred your XML to come back row-wise

```
SELECT B.value('@Code','int') AS Code
      ,B.value('.','int') AS Value
FROM @xml.nodes('/Attributes/Attribute') A(B);
```

--use this query as CTE and do your filtering with normal WHERE

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT B.value('@Code','int') AS Code
          ,B.value('.','int') AS Value
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Attributes/Attribute') A(B)
)
SELECT Code, Value
FROM MyCTE
WHERE Code=1;
```

If you want to make this as easy as possible, you should create a function.

If you are only interested in one value, this should be a scalar function returning the value to one (or several) parameters you pass in.

If you might be interested in several nodes fullfilling your filter you should create an (inlineable) table valued function.

Come back if you need further help...

Comment: thanks for helping , but how can I use your code in C# , I use `Entity framework` and Linq , and I should write queries with these providers.

Comment: @temp125050 I'd create a SQL function and call this from C# code. If you deal with big/many XMLs and you want to do the logic in your application, you'd have to load the whole lot first - much traffic...